# Survival analysis with rare events

Tags: survival, cox-model

I want to model survival using Cox regression using R. I have a binary outcome (yes/no) with low prevalence so I would like to apply a correction such as Firth's correction – is this appropriate? I was planning to use the `coxphf` command although the Help file states this is generally used for non-convergence. My standard Cox model does converge but I am just wondering if I should apply any correction due to the small number of cases… Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

With rare events, problems can occur with convergence if there are no events for some particular combinations of predictor values. So, *on that account*, you don't need a correction if your model is converging.

You might, however, consider some type of penalization if you have a large number of predictors relative to the number of events. Then rare events can lead to a problem of overfitting. A usual rule of thumb is to have at least 10-20 events per predictor in the model (including extra levels of multi-level categorical variables and interaction terms). If you are at danger of overfitting because of a low event/predictor ratio, Firth's correction [might be used](https://doi.org/10.1002/bimj.201600226) in such circumstances, but ridge regression is probably a more typical and generally familiar penalization method for this type of study.

Comment: Thank you for your response - can I run a ridge regression within survival analysis? would you be able to advise on which command can be used in R to do so?

Comment: @Francesca it's simplest to use the [`glmnet` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnet), with vignettes showing its general use and its application to Cox models. Chapter 6 of [ISLR](https://www.statlearning.com) works through `glmnet` for linear regression; same approach applies to Cox. Set `alpha = 0` for ridge regression and use `cv.glmnet()` to find the optimal penalty; best to use the default `deviance` criterion for that in Cox models. You don't use a standard R formula, however. You specify a matrix of predictors and a `Surv()` object outcome separately.